# Cube does not connect

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, cube

I have created a Cube but I can't it to connect. In the Browser it keeps saying that "A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that SQL Browser service is running."  and if I click more information it says that "No connection could be made because the target machine activerly refused it 127.0.0.1:2382 (System)".

I made sure I have all the following services running.
[image]

But still doesn't work.

I have put rules in the Firewall to allow the ports 2382 and 2823. Nothing.
I changed the Server Target project from Localhost to my particular server. Nothing.

I still need to try to install SQL Server Analysis Service to try that as I don't have it in my current services but I can't find a place to download it and install.

Any ideas in how to solve this?

Comment: there is no service for ssas. there should be service of SQL Server Analysis Service

Comment: How and from where can I install that service?

Comment: when you install sql server, there is option for it